# How can I add a Cordova plugin into Ionic 2 project?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic2, matomo

For instance, if I would like to use Piwik plugin provided by Cordova, how could I integrate it into my Ionic 2 project?

Especially how can I invoke the plugin in the project.

E.g.
If I have already added a plugin named Plugin with Cordova, how can I invoke it?

In the file `Home.ts`, how can I instantiate it?

```
let plugin = new Plugin();
```

doesn't work. My editor will say `Plugin not found` or this sort of things.

Answer (score 2):

You should do `ionic plugin add NAME_OF_THE_PLUGIN` Than you should be able to normally use the object that the plugin is exposing. If you are using typescript and dont want it to complain, you can write: `declare var name_of_the_variable` so it will not throw errors.
Also ionic will add the plugin in its list of plugins so next time you add a new platform or ionic state reset the project, it will fetch the plugins automatically.

Also you can learn about Dependency Injection and Inject it manually @Inject('name_of_variable') and than use it in all your classes.

More on DI: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html

Edit: for some of the cordova plugins, ionic provides some 'wrappers' that you can use. You can read more about that here: http://www.joshmorony.com/using-cordova-plugins-in-ionic-2-with-ionic-native/.

Also if you have problems angular detecting the changes (I had a problem like this) You can wrap the calls from the plugin into `ngZone.run(() => { ... } )`. You also need to ask angular to provide you the instance of the current zone in the constructor `constructor(ngZone: NgZone)`

I hope it helps

Comment: I mean, how can I instantiate or new an object of the plugin?

Comment: You dont need to call new Plugin(), As I can see from the documentation the plugin exposes a variable ```piwik```. You do not need to instantiate the plugin, cordova does that for you so the variable ```pikwik``` exists from the beginning just like some other variables that the browser provides like ```document``` or ```window```..

Comment: And what should I import? Because here (https://github.com/kriserickson/cordova-piwik-plugin/blob/master/README.md) didn't tell me how would I use piwik.startTracker(), and if I invoke this function, it will cause a `object not found`

Comment: inside platform.ready handler call ```console.log(piwik)``` and check if it exists. You dont need to import anything, cordova exposes the object as a global object that exists everywhere

Comment: The problem is that there's always the exception: `piwik is not defined`

Comment: Are you logging it inside platform.ready? If you are than check if you have the plugin in the list of plugins (type in terminal cordova plugin list)

Comment: Yes.`cordova plugin list
com.storefront.cordova.piwik 0.0.1 "Piwik"`

Comment: Check this issue out: https://github.com/kriserickson/cordova-piwik-plugin/issues/2. His answer also states that the piwik object exists

Comment: I added `Piwik` with cordova plugin add xxxx`, then I just use `piwik.startTracker()`. But always `piwik is not defined`..

Comment: Try ionic platform remove android or ios and try readding it again or try ```ionic state reset```, than check the list of plugins

Comment: Again, are you calling that inside platform.ready? here is a screenshot of platform ready http://prntscr.com/bddjvt. And just console.log(piwik) and see if it is undefined, do not call startTracker(). You need to be sure that the object exists. If you are calling it outside platform ready and at the beggining of the app start it will be undefined

Comment: Yes, I called it in platform.ready().then(()=>{}), but as I told you, doesn't work. Should I add something in the argument of constructor?

Comment: No, I made a blank ionic app and added the plugin, it works fine. Here is a screenshot. http://prntscr.com/bddmik 
1. I started ionic project
2. I added ```cordova plugin add https://github.com/kriserickson/cordova-piwik-plugin```
3. I console logged the object in platform ready and it works, its not undefined

Comment: Do I have to add something in my `package.json`?

Comment: No you do not, if you read my last comment, create a blank new project and try it will work

Comment: OK, I'll try it. But another problem has come up. Could you help me to solve it? Here's the link of the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679723/after-reset-plugins-ionic-2-program-doesnt-work