# After reseting plugins, Ionic 2 program doesn't work?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I used many plugins in my Ionic 2 project. All things works fine before. But after launching `ionic state reset --plugins`, some objects cannot be found any more.

I've used Beacon Plugin in my project.

----edit----

What it doesn't work is
`Cannot read property 'Delegate' of undefined` in `var delegate = new this.locationManager.Delegate();`

----edit----

The most weird thing is that `ionic serve` works (Browser), but `ionic run android` (Device) doesn't.

----edit----

After `ionic platform rm android` and `ionic platform add android`, still doesn't works.

----edit----

Doesn't work even I reinstall the `Cordova`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command

```
ionic state reset --plugins
```

removes everything and then bring back what you have specified in the `package.json` file. Is the Beacon Plugin reference in your project's `package.json` file? If not, you will have to run

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon.git
```

to add it again. Once everything is working again, you can run the following command in order to save current plugins / platforms to the `package.json`:

```
ionic state save
```

And then, if you need to quickly load in plugins and platforms, you can simply do:

```
ionic state restore
```

And Ionic will add in the appropriate plugins and platforms.